# Как убрать фоновую заливку в svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, svg

Есть **svg**, он соединен через **use** с тегом **path**, в котором нарисован логотип из линий. На странице он отображается полностью залитым, а нужно, чтобы заливки не было, только обводка. Пытался изменить стиль заливки с помощью **fill-rule**, но это не помогает.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class='logo'>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                viewBox="200 50 600 550">
                    <use xlink:href='#logo'></use>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <nav>

            </nav>
        </header>
    <svg>
        <path id='logo' d='M 200 400 L 400 50 L 600 400 L 500 400 L 400 50 L 500 400 L 400 550 L 300 400 L 400 50 L 400 550 L 300 400 L 200 400 ' stroke='blue'></path>
    </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `fill="transparent"` ?

Comment: `fill="none"` вообще-то

Answer (score 1):

Вам уже  правильно ответил @Alexey Ten  в комментариях: чтобы убрать заливку цветом нужно добавить атрибут `fill="none"`. Так как у вас не был указан этот атрибут, то  SVG по умолчанию всё заливает чёрным цветом.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class='logo'>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                viewBox="200 50 600 550">
                    <use xlink:href='#logo' fill="none" ></use>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <nav>

            </nav>
        </header>
    <svg>
        <path id='logo'  d='M 200 400 L 400 50 L 600 400 L 500 400 L 400 50 L 500 400 L 400 550 L 300 400 L 400 50 L 400 550 L 300 400 L 200 400'  stroke='blue'></path>
    </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Как правило так поступают (не указывая `fill` ), когда хотят с помощью тега `<use>` многократно использовать (клонировать) один и тот же элемент svg.

И тогда при вызове каждого клона можно его либо не окрашивать совсем (как вы хотите), 
либо окрашивать в любой, например - красный цвет с помощью `fill="red"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class='logo'>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                viewBox="200 50 600 550">
                   <g transform="translate(60,30) scale(0.7)">
     <use xlink:href='#logo' fill="none" ></use>
       </g>   
        <g transform="translate(260,40) scale(0.5)">
      <use xlink:href='#logo' fill="yellowgreen" ></use>
        </g>    
        <g transform="translate(460,50) scale(0.25)">
      <use xlink:href='#logo' fill="gold" ></use>
     </g>        
                </svg>
            </div>
            <nav>

            </nav>
        </header>
    <svg>
        <path id='logo'  d='M 200 400 L 400 50 L 600 400 L 500 400 L 400 50 L 500 400 L 400 550 L 300 400 L 400 50 L 400 550 L 300 400 L 200 400'  stroke='blue'></path>
    </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы визуально убрать фон заливки, можно его сделать полностью прозрачным, добавив `fill-opacity='0'`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class='logo'>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                viewBox="200 50 600 550">
                    <use xlink:href='#logo'></use>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <nav>

            </nav>
        </header>
    <svg>
        <path id='logo' d='M 200 400 L 400 50 L 600 400 L 500 400 L 400 50 L 500 400 L 400 550 L 300 400 
                           L 400 50 L 400 550 L 300 400 L 200 400 ' 
                           stroke='blue'
                           fill-opacity='0'
                           ></path>
    </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```